# Can't trade or accept trades

Tags: clash-royale

My king is level 8, I'm in arena 12, and I have one of each trade tokens but I can't trade or accept trades. Can anyone help with that? Is there something I'm missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following quantities are swapped in trades:

- Common: 250
- Rare: 50
- Epic: 10
- Legendary: 1

This means if you want to make an epic trade, you would need to have at least 10 of a single epic in your inventory to give away. Based on the screenshot, you have around 0 to 4 of each epic card, which is not enough to trade.

As for legendaries, according to the [wiki](https://clashroyale.fandom.com/wiki/Trade_Tokens)... "Players cannot trade away the last Legendary card that unlocks it. For example, if a player's Miner is at level 9 with upgrade meter "1/2", they cannot trade it away." This means if you've only ever acquired one of a particular legendary, you cannot trade it.

Comment: Does that mean i have to upgrade my epic before i can trade and if so what level

Comment: I have two legendary level 9, why cant i trade them?

Comment: No you don't need to upgrade anything before you can trade. You just need to have enough cards to trade with. For example you have 2/4 dark prince. If you had 10/4 dark prince then you'd have enough dark prince to give away for a trade.

Comment: @MeronHabtemariam According to the [wiki](https://clashroyale.fandom.com/wiki/Trade_Tokens)... "Players cannot trade away the last Legendary card that unlocks it. For example, if a player's Miner is at level 9 with upgrade meter "1/2", they cannot trade it away."

Comment: Thxs so much now i understand